# Cut and paste values from sheet 1 to the next available row on sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to cut and past values from a range of cells on sheet 1 to the next available row on sheet 2. All guides and advice I've seen has been for copying and pasting and for same sheet.

Range on sheet 1 is E5-H5 to be cut, not copied, and then pasted to sheet 2, cells E7-H7 or the next available row below that as each time someone enters data I need sheet 2 to keep it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. People come here with specific problems they have with their code. There are other sites which help you to learn how to code VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Don't select. I post this answer more to help @KoderM16 improve their methods than to answer the original question:

```
Sub CutPaste()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E5:H5").Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Also this doesn't make sense as it returns true or false (will most likely always be true because it can in fact select that address):

```
Lastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

You would want .row on the end instead of .select if you want to assign the row to `Lastrow`, you don't however then use `lastrow`.

With your code as it is, lastrow would most likely always be -1 as that is the value for True

Answer (score 0):

The below code will copy your range and look for the 1st empty cell (from the bottom up) in column E, Sheet 2, to paste. Hope this helps.

```
Sub CutPaste()

Dim Lastrow As Long

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E5:H5").Copy
Lastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

As you are new to Stack Overflow and probably vba as well, just try to adhere to the comment above by Peh. Your question, while not specifically, is easily googlable in parts. Also, if this answers your question, please tick it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am new and apologise for misusing the website.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am new and apologise for misusing the website. I have tried googling the different parts of the macro i require and unfortunately cannot find what I am looking for as all i find in google is how to copy and paste. I would have posted the code that ive tried typing but feared there were so many mistakes with it that it would be a waste of everyones time trying to decipher it.     I have tried the code you have so kindly provided for me and found that it does not work. i get error 1004. not sure exactly what this means.

Comment: Don't use select. I will post a change below regarding this but mark KoderM16's as correct as he helped you out first, I just pulled the select out and cleaned up the code.

Comment: @skip just keep on working with vba and coding and soon you will start to read code like you read a book. I have only been in it for over a month or so and its starting to get easier.

Comment: @DanDonoghue Thanks man! I saw the Select and Selection.PasteSpecial method somewhere else early on and I haven't been able to kick the habit lol